# SQL finding average between dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, average

I have the user write in two dates, say: '2013-7-8','2013-7-15' 
The stored procedure then executes and returns and updated table. 
Two columns include:

## Avg_Paid_Volume ---- cns_amt

numb_im_looking_for -------------------------10000 
numb_im_looking_for ------------------------ 20000 
numb_im_looking_for -------------------------30000 
... etc


cns_amt is just volume over the specified time period. 
I'm looking for the average paid volume across between the specified two dates, which i called @dt_from and @dt_to -> in this case it would be 10000/8, 20000/8 and 30000/8


I would like to have those values inputed into my table (into the 'numb_im_looking_for')

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @dt_to datetime
Declare @dt_from datetime
set @dt_to = convert(datetime,'2013-7-8')
set @dt_from = convert(datetime,'2013-7-15')

Update tableName
Set avg_paid_volume = (cns_amt / datediff(d,@dt_to,@dt_from))
```

datediff is key here

Comment: actually, is there a way where you dont have to manually input '2013-7-8' and '2013-7-15' within the convert() and just have it so you can exec procedure '2013-7-8', '2013'7'15' and have those dates automatically used in the convert function

Comment: yeah that was more to just to show that the convert to datetime was necessary, the exec procedure is the better way.